# Celery worker name, how to call a remote task

Tags: python, django, celery

When I list my remote workers using celery:

```
 celery -A project status
```

I notice the worker has a number at the end:

```
celery@email_worker.dabe315d425f2
```

By what name should I refer to my worker by? i.e.

```
celery.send_task('tasks.email_worker', args=[instance.id], kwargs={})
```

or

```
celery.send_task('tasks.email_worker.dabe315d425f2', args=[instance.id], kwargs={})
```